# Change URL to .html

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can I change this URL

`http://mysite.com/index.php?searchterm=my+great+song`

to

`http://mysite.com/search/my-great-song.html`

I am a beginner in mod_rewrite. That is why I can not figure out what to do. I would appreciate your help if you can tell me the .htaccess code that I should write in the .htaccess file to change the url.

Comment: You need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchterm=(.*)$` with `%1` to get your search term in your RewriteRule. Then simply apply a rule that rewrites one space in an url and replaces that with a - and repeat that rule until it doesn't match anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^\.]+).html$ /index.php?searchterm=$1
```

Comment: Didn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. Can you try this new code and sent a real url to see if code is working ?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I tried its work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^search/([^\.]+).html$ /index.php?searchterm=$1

Options All -Indexes

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following htaccess should work for you

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:stripspaces} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$ $1-$2 [N]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchterm=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search/%1.html? [E=stripspaces:1,E=redirect:1,N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R,E=!stripspaces,E=!redirect]
```

I use environment variables `[E=a:b]` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e)) to control when spaces should be stripped and to prevent extensive amounts of redirects. The `N` flag makes the rewriteengine start from the top of the .htaccess file again. Therefore I put the stripspaces rule in the top, to minimize the amount of rules that need to be matched. The `%1` in the second rules is a backreference to the first capture group in the rewritecondition. The trailing `?` clears the query string. The documentation for all this can be found on [httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).