# Need to convert %20 to - using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
# ENABLE REWRITE ENGINE
RewriteEngine On

# CONVERT \s and %20 to MINUS SIGN
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

I have used the following snippet of code towards the top of my htaccess file but it does not work. I've also tried other snippets from stackoverflow and they didn't work either. Where am I going wrong? Seems to work for other people but not me :)

Reason I need this is because my form submission to GET always converts spaces to %20..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `%{THE_REQUEST}` will ALWAYS contain spaces. It is in the form of `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`. The url itself will never contain actual spaces, because that is an invalid character in an url. It will always be in the form of `%20`. What I suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785162/change-url-to-html/17787405#17787405) was something like this:

```
#This will rewrite every single space in the url to a dash
RewriteCond %{ENV:stripspaces} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$ $1-$2 [N]

#This will tell that when the requirements for this rule are met,
#spaces should be rewritten.
#You probably don't want that top happen for each url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %20
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [E=stripspaces:1,E=redirect:1,N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R,E=!stripspaces,E=!redirect,QSA]
```

I think this will work for you too. If you really want to rewrite every single space everywhere, you use a much simpler construction:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,E=redirect:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R,E=!redirect,QSA]
```

Comment: Nope just tried both these and neither worked. Something strange is going on. I tried such things almost at the top of my .htaccess and same result. Really weird.

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled? Are you sure the rewriteengine is on?